# Создание собственной аутентификации

Tags: аутентификация, ruby, auth, ruby-on-rails

Есть таблица `Users`, в ней [`id, login, password, level`]
Что можно придумать для авторизации пользователя, чтобы в дальнейшем проверять его `level` где нибудь **во вьюхе** ? Ну и соответственно в зависимости от `level` выводить ему какие либо данные.
Пытался сделать это через `session`, так `session` недоступен из модели.

На пример, где нибудь во вьюхе:

```
<% if Auth::User.is_auth? %>
  <div class="ok"> Авторизирован, логин: <%= Auth::User.login</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Вам нужна именно своя аутентификация?

Comment: Да, я как бы новичок и хотелось бы разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите разобраться - двигайтесь по этому [руководству](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/a-demo-app#top) например + видео [скринкасты](http://rails.hasbrains.org/) там тоже есть как про аутентификацию и про многое другое.

А после своей реализации посмотрите на `gem devise` и используйте его (при нужде после форка на гитхабе сможете его "улучшить", хотя это маловероятно).